# user_passes_test decorator redirecting to login even when result is True

Tags: python, django

This is my decorator:

```
def is_clinic(user):
    user.groups.filter(name='Klinik').exists()
```

And my view:

```
class Index(View):
    @method_decorator(login_required)
    @method_decorator(user_passes_test(is_clinic, login_url='/clinic_only.html'))
    def get(self, request):
        return render(request,"index.html")
```

user is in group. I tested it with shell and decorator is returning True for sure.

When i navigate to url, django is redirecting me to `clinic_only.html`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have forgotten to return the result of your query. Therefore, your function implicitly returns `None`, and the decorator redirects to the login page. You should have:

```
def is_clinic(user):
    return user.groups.filter(name='Klinik').exists()
```

Comment: Well, i totally missed that. Thank you!

Comment: Easily done, another second pair of eyes often helps!